# Stay in the active workbook after opening other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open two other Excel workbooks to take data to do my calculation through the macro. I have a working code to open those files.

```
Dim wbCount As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For wbCount = 1 To 2
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Installation Sheet " & wbCount & ".xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
Next wbCount
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The other files are named "Installation Sheet 1" and "Installation Sheet 2". After this code runs, I end up with "Installation Sheet 1" displaying instead of my active workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `ActiveWorkbook` into a variable at the appropriate place and then use that to move back. `ThisWorkbook` is the one with code in. So be sure if you mean `ActiveWorkbook` or `ThisWorkbook`, or if `ThisWorkbook` is the `ActiveWorkbook` at the time. In that case, you can simply `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'Set wb = ThisWorkbook   '<== If you want the workbook containing the code
'Other code
wb.Activate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestion. I tried your solution but I am still getting the same result. Here is the updated code. @QHarr

Comment: Is it the workbook with the code in that you want at the front at the end?

Comment: Yes. I need the workbook on which I am writing this macro to be at the front.

Comment: Set wb =ThisWorkbook . At the end of your looping then put wb.Activate and it should come to the front.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your workbooks references into variables and then using these variables you have two options: close newly opened workbook, so only original stays opened or use `Activate` method to bring the original workbook to front.

Sample code:

```
Sub OpeningWb()
    Dim wb As Workbook, currentWb As Workbook
    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("your path here")
    ' if you want to close opened workbook
    'wb.Close
    ' if you want to bring to front original workbook
    currentWb.Activate
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
Dim wbToDisplay As Workbook
Set wbToDisdplay = Workbooks("workbook name here")
wbToDisplay.Activate
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I tried your suggestion but I still ending up with the same result. Below is the revised code:

Comment: @ Michal Turczyn Your original solution is now working but after I removed the SreenUpdate Statements. Can you please tell me the reason. I turned the screen update off because I did not want my screen to flicker.

Comment: @ShashankBanerjee It doesn't affect behavior on mine computer. If I use `ScreenUpdating = False` it still works as supposed to.

Comment: Turczyn Thanks a lot for replying. I will research this a bit more. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ShashankBanerjee If my answer helped you you should accept it and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't work for me, because activate method is fired before second workbook is displayed, so I get active this second workbook always. My workaround is wait a couple of seconds before calling Activate method:

```
Dim t: t = Timer
While Timer < t + 2 'wait for 2 seconds
    DoEvents
Wend
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming in late on this one but I couldn't find an answer that worked for me. I don't know the mechanisms behind it all but no matter what I do it will never reactivate the original wbk after opening a new one unless I completely remove the screenupdating = FALSE. I've tried various ways of re-activating the original, but despite being able to interact via in the code the new wbk won't actually open until the script finishes even after the screenupdating is theoretically disabled. My solution was to force a screen update with a blank userform which instantly deactivates when loaded. Not the most elegant but works 100% of the time for me.

```
Dim wbCount As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For wbCount = 1 To 2
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Installation Sheet " & wbCount & ".xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False
Next wbCount

Load BlankForm 
BlankForm.Show
ThisWorkBook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE

-------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserForm_Activate() 'Instantly deactivate userform on Activation
        Unload BlankForm
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).